# quantifying relatedness of populations in high dimensional featurespace

Tags: regression, t-test

I am not sure if this is the correct Stack Exchange for this question, please correct me if I should move it.

I am currently working with some high dimensional data. I would like to compare two  populations and get quantitative measures of their similarity, I have the following questions.

Assuming that the data is normally distributed can I just run a t-test? Several other tests have been suggested to me including regression, however I am not sure what the advantages of these tests over a t-test. I would like to know if both populations overlap in feature space, not just if the means are similar, would I be ignoring this with a t-test?

Edit: I also could not confidently say that the variance scales with population size.

I would also like to know if there is high overlap between one population and a sub-population of another group, is there a good test for that?

The data has been prepossessed to remove batch effects, will this likely have an effect on testing, or should I include batch effect removal in the quantification step?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A t-test is a univariate test designed for one variable, if you have more than one variable than a linear model (not a test) is a better choice. A t-test will not take into consideration the other variables when calculating results, which is what a linear model will do.

If you have heteroskedasticity (increasing / decreasing variance) then you can also model this with a linear model, a t-test cannot do that.

Comparing different groups / subpopulations is as easy as creating a factor variable in a linear model.

You should not remove the batch effects but rather include them in the model, this may require a mixed model.

Comment: Thank you I will do more reading on linear models!